# "part of the time", but "a good part of the day"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, articles, singular-vs-plural, collocations

#### Citation from [Definition of "part" noun from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/part_1?q=part):

> We spent part of the time in the museum.

> We spent a good part of the day rehearsing.

#### Question

Are there some reasons why an article "a" is used in the second sentence but the first sentence?
Or is it optional to use "a" for these sentences?

#### Related posts on StackExchange:

I found several related posts, but I think they don't directly answer my question.

- [difference between “part” and “a part”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/224909/127344)
- [“A part” or “parts”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8350/127344)
- [When to use “a part”, “part”, and “parts”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/228770/127344)

Comment: The reason is the presence of the adjective. _Part of the day_ doesn't specify how big a part it was. _A large part, a small part, a good (meaning large) part_ all require the indefinite article. We can also say _the greater part_, which imagines that the day (or whatever) is divided into two parts and this is the larger one.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your reply. So can "little" be used like "little part of the day" since it can be used with uncountables?

Comment: When you say 'it can be used with uncountables', do you mean _little_ in the sense of _not much_? When it describes a part it is an adjective like _small_, so it needs an article.